# jQuery Validation - Duplicate jquery validator error messages when loading dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, model-view-controller

I'm loading a partial page (MVC) using jquery ajax. The partial page contains a form that needs to be validated using jquery validator.

The form is parsed again after dynamic elements are inserted.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "Base/partialPageUrl",
                success: function (data) {
                    //Load Dynamic Form
                    $(href).html(data);

                    //Reinitialize Validators
                    var form = $(formSelector)
                        .removeData("validator") 
                        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                }
            });
```

The validation works fine but inserts the error message twice.

[image: Duplicate Error Messages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by using $(form).valid() instead of the default submit action

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close the question.